# How can I find cell with minimum value in a column and add the values next to it to another range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have values in range `A1:A3` and also in `B1:D3`.I would like to find the cell with minimum value in range `A1:A3` and to add the all row values next to that cell to another range by hitting a command button.

I can find the cell with minimum value but I can't insert the values next to that cell to a range.

Here `A2` is the cell with minimum value.
What I have to do is adding the values in `B2:D2` to another empty range when I hit a command button.

See image below - where yellow highlight shows the answer after hitting the command button.

[image]

Comment: Super User is not a VBA script writing service. You will have to give detailed information about what you have attempted, what VBA you have so far and where you are stuck. We are here to help you from there, but not here to do it for you. Reading ***[ask]*** may help you better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

If VBA (the command button!) is not a mandatory option you can achieve the same as shown below.
[image]
Formula `=IF(MIN($A$1:$A$3)=A3,SUM(B3:D3),"")`
I used your example with `A1:A3` and `B1:D3` to illustrate this answer.
Please comment if command button is mandatory - then I will add an edit to add the VBA code to my answer

Comment: I have edited the question and command button is mandatory